# SQL Server Querying Online

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL Server database servers in two different server computers.

- Server A - 192.168.1.100
- Server B - 192.168.2.102

I need to execute a query from server A to retrieve data from a table in the Server B.

How to write the SQL select statement to perform this?

Are there any server configurations to allow these type of querying?

Comment: One way is to define linked server and  use 4-part name `linked_server.db_name.schema_name.table_name`

Comment: Please don't type your question title in ALL CAPS. That's considered SHOUTING here, and there's no need to do so. We can all read quite well, and SHOUTING your question will not get you an answer more quickly. It's also rather rude to SHOUT at people you're asking for help. :-)

Comment: Use MSSMS to connect to your SQL Server.  Expand the Server Instance.  Expand Server Objects, then expand Linked Servers.  You can link to your other server and like lad2025 mentioned, use the 4-part name to reference the server in your query.

Comment: I also up-voted this question because it is a good beginners inquiry,  regardless of the Upper Case.

Answer (score 1):

Add a linked server here are commands for 1 way of doing this. replace the user and password values with an appropriate SQL credential.

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'192.168.2.102', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
EXECUTE master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'192.168.2.102',@useself=N'False',@rmtuser='ASQLLogin',@rmtpassword='Password'
```

then simply query like you would a normal table but append the linked server in front as commented above linked_server.db_name.schema_name.table_name like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
     [192.168.2.102].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

You can even join it to your local server A if you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
     [192.168.2.102].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] b
     INNER JOIN SomeTableOnServerA a
     ON b.ID = a.ID
```